# How can I tell whether a given linux distro's wifi is managed via NetworkManager vs wpa_supplicant?

Tags: linux, wifi, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant

It seems like different distros use either wpa_supplicant or NetworkManager to handle their wifi connections. It also appears to be the case that these are mutually exclusive and aren't meant to be used together.

Where can I find which distros use which methods to manage their connections?

Comment: You could kill the processes and see what happens to your WIFI connection.

Comment: That's a great idea! I hadn't thought of that. That works great if I'm already running the distro - is there a spec sheet somewhere where I can see what ships with a given distro ahead of time?

Comment: It looks like if it uses network manager, it also uses wpa_supplicant in the backend. More information can be found on this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1786/what-is-the-difference-between-network-manager-and-ifconfig-ifup-etc

Answer (score 1):

[`wpa_supplicant`](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/wpasupplicant/wpa_supplicant.8.en.html) is a wireless daemon, it can work independently from the network managers (e,g: [NetworkManager](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/NetworkManager), wicd, connman ...)

NetworkManager require a wireless daemon to manage WPA : wpa_supplicant , [iwd](/questions/tagged/iwd) .

Answer (score -1):

use `ps aux` to get the computer processes and `grep` for finding the process

```
ps aux | grep network
```

output on Macintosh:

```
_networkd          206   0.0  0.1  4385868   8148   ??  Ss   Sun02PM   0:24.95 /usr/libexec/symptomsd
```